# Is it possible to log to file using SLF4j without line feeds?

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

Is it possible to log to file using SLF4j  without line feeds?

Basically, I have a waitTimer() method that prints a "." once per second and I want all the dots to appear on one line in the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html), if you have %n in your log4j layout, line separator such as "\n" will be appended at each message automatically. Remove it will make all messages appear in one line. But if you also want to keep other message with line feeds, you'd better define two appender.